# How to prevent session based on role in react? [Firebase]

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a newbie to react and currently developing an application,

**BACKGROUND:**

It has admin, faculty, student, dashboards and a static landing page with buttons  to /admin/login ,/faculty/login ,/student/login. which opens respective dashboards.

**PROBLEM:**

when I log in with student's login i am able to access all the dashboards & vice-versa, i have a field named role inside my firebase nodes,

while logging in i check user's role and it  doesn't allow other users with  other roles to login ,but once after i login i am able to access all dashboards(which should not happen) including the dashboard which i am supposed to open , i am using react and routes.js, my public and private routes files are below.

***ROUTES.js***

```
const Routes = props => {
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Switch>
        <AdminPublicRoute
          {...props}
          exact
          restricted={true}
          path="/admin/login"
          component={AdminLogin}
        />
        <AdminPrivateRoute
          {...props}
          path="/admin/admindashboard"
          exact
          component={AdminDash}
        />
<FacultyPublicRoute
          {...props}
          exact
          restricted={true}
          path="/faculty/login"
          component={FacultyLogin}
        />
        <FacultyPrivateRoute
          {...props}
          path="/faculty/facultydashboard"
          exact
          component={FacultyDash}
        />
<StudentPublicRoute
          {...props}
          exact
          restricted={true}
          path="/student/login"
          component={StudentLogin}
        />
        <StudentPrivateRoute
          {...props}
          path="/student/studentdashboard"
          exact
          component={StudentDash}
        />
 </Switch>
    </MainLayout>
```

***ADMINPRIVATEROUTE.js***

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

    const AdminPrivateRoutes = ({ user, component: Comp, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          component={props =>
            user ? <Comp {...props} user={user} /> : <Redirect to="/admin/login" />
          }
        />
      );
    };

    export default AdminPrivateRoutes;
```

***ADMINPUBLICROUTE.js***

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AdminPublicRoutes = ({ user, component: Comp, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      component={props =>
        rest.restricted ? (
          user ? (
            <Redirect to="/admin/admindashboard" />
          ) : (
            <Comp {...props} user={user} />
          )
        ) : (
          <Comp {...props} user={user} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default AdminPublicRoutes;
```

***FACULTYPRIVATEROUTE.js***

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

    const FacultyPrivateRoutes = ({ user, component: Comp, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          component={props =>
            user ? <Comp {...props} user={user} /> : <Redirect to="/faculty/login" />
          }
        />
      );
    };

    export default FacultyPrivateRoutes;
```

***FACULTYPUBLICROUTE.js***

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const FacultyPublicRoutes= ({ user, component: Comp, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      component={props =>
        rest.restricted ? (
          user ? (
            <Redirect to="/faculty/facultydashboard" />
          ) : (
            <Comp {...props} user={user} />
          )
        ) : (
          <Comp {...props} user={user} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default FacultyPublicRoutes;
```

Any suggestions,hints would be helpful, thanks in advance.

[image: STRUCTURE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using React Router, you can conditionally render routes

```
<Switch>
  <FacultyPublicRoute {...props} />
  {isFaculty && <FacultyPrivateRoute {...props} />}
  <StudentPublicRoute {...props} />
  {isStudent && <StudentPrivateRoute {...props} />}
</Switch>
```

Comment: sir,how do i traverse all the nodes and check the role field

Comment: you should store data about user role (after login) in global storage like contextapi or redux